# Django Forn Not Saving Extra Information

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I extended the Django AbstratUser so that users can use email to sign in and signup, these work perfectly. The problem I am facing, however, is that the extra information on the extended model is not storing the information in the database, even though the user gets created. Once I hit the submit button, the user and extended model get created, and while the user model stores the information, the extended model is always empty.

I have tried using both `signals` and `@transaction_atomic`, yet, I have not been able to figure it out. Maybe I am missing out something, I do not know.

Models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(_('Company name'), max_length=250)
    ...        
    #more information
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Company')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Companies')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CompanySignUpForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Company name'}))
    ...        
    #more fields
    ...

    class Meta(CustomUserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_company = True
        user.save()
        company = Company.objects.create(user=user)
        company.name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        ...        
        #more information
        ...
        return user
```

Views.py

```
def company_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanySignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'accounts/templates/company_success.html')
    else:
        form = CompanySignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/templates/company_signup.html', context={
        'title': _('Create a Company Account'),
        'form': form,
    })
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to @Mandrup, I was able to extend his solution to fit my need.

**forms.py**

```
class CompanySignUpForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Company name'}))
    number_of_employees = forms.CharField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Number of employees'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Contact Number'}))
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), required=True, empty_label="Country")

    class Meta(CustomUserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CompanySignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            user.is_company = True
            user.save()
            name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
            number_of_employees = self.cleaned_data.get('number_of_employees')
            phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            country = self.cleaned_data.get('country')
            company = Company(user=user, name=name, number_of_employees=number_of_employees, phone=phone, country=country)
            company.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

This worked for me when i tried to create an extended user profile. I changed it to fit your needs.

Model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ...        
    #more information
    ...


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Form:

```
class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]#add whatever fields you want to here




    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterUserForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            user.save()

            company = Company(user=user, name='Company name')
            company.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Like I explained earlier, I tried signals, it did not work. In fact, anytime I use signal, the Company object doesn't get created. But if I use transaction_atomic, it gets created but the information doesn't get saved.

Comment: Hmmm that's weird.

Comment: I was able to extend your solution to fit my need. Problem solved! Thank you @Mandrup